# Book about a girl who found a portal in the woods to a violent and ruthless fairy world

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, magic, fairy

From what I remember this girl found a portal in the woods to a fairy world but the fairies went more along with Grimm tales, they were violent and ruthless. A lot of people are trying to kidnap her and she eventually gets taken to this castle where she finds out that her father is the king of this kingdom and wants her to lead his army to war with the other fairy kingdoms.

I'm sorry this isn't a lot to go off of. I read this back in 2015.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall the cover art or any character names?  Was this a printed book or an e-book?

Comment: I remember that the cover was white with an oval on it and inside the oval was a portrait of the main character, who was African American. There were twigs around the oval and I think the title was also on the border of the oval, if not it was above. Also when I read this trilogy, it was an e-book on my Kindle.